# Gradle multi-project build: How to execute the default task(s) of a subproject?

Tags: gradle

It's easy to execute the default task(s) of a Gradle project (just run gradle without parameters in the project directory), and it's also easy to run a particular subproject task from the root project directory (run gradle :subprojectName:taskName). But how can you run the default task(s) of a subproject when you are in the directory of the root project (and too lazy to cd to the subdir)?

Is this a feature the Gradle designers forgot to implement, or am I unable to read the documentation?

Comment: the default task is `help` ...so what you mean by "default task"?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, none of the following notations for task path will work: `gradle :subproject` will be interpreted as "task subproject from root project", `gradle :subproject:` will be interpreted as "task ' '  from subproject" .

Comment: @MartinZeitler: You can define your own default tasks in a Gradle build file, e.g. "defaultTasks 'clean', 'run'"

Comment: maybe this is not what you want , but a workaround to execute all default tasks (from all sub-project) from the root project directory is described here : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-run-defaults-tasks-of-sub-project-rather-than-default-tasks-of-root-project/6575/2  . but it's a workaround...

Comment: I think it's missing unfortunately ... would make sense to have this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! A task can depend on another task from a sub-project, it seems like. I'm running Gradle 8.5.

My gradle root has a runnable project, and couple of libraries. It's spring boot so I'm running gradle bootRun from my runnable project.

Do run it from the root, I have simply created a build.gradle in the root with this:

```
task bootRun(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn(':my_runnable:bootRun')
}
```

Hence, I no longer have to cd my_runnable. Hope this helps!